# Print pdf from iis Website using from remote PC

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am generating pdf using itextsharp and print that pdf.
when i run project from Visual Studio print command is working.

when i host project in iis and access webpage from remote PC, Print Command is not working.

I am using Below Code for Printing

```
Process printjob = new Process();
printjob.StartInfo.FileName = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/") + "Document" + Month + "-" + Year + ".pdf"; //path of your file;
printjob.StartInfo.Verb = "Print";
printjob.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
printjob.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
PrinterSettings setting = new PrinterSettings();
setting.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
printjob.Start();
```

Comment: _"…is not working…"_ — Still one of the most detailed error descriptions ever.

Comment: Is the file being generated on the server? Do you have a printer on the iis machine? Does your application pool user have access rights to the folder, and authorization to print something? Does the application throw an exception, and if yes, what exception and what is the message? All things you could and should check, and include the results in your question

Comment: You are starting a process on the server. So the client will never get a PDF.

Comment: I have installed Printer drivers in Server Machine, but when i run website using visual studio above code is working fine, but when i print from client side it is not printing document